# why react Router is not working . when i change the path?

Tags: reactjs, router, react-router-dom, react-dom

**react route path is not working**
**it shows only product component in all URL**

I Have instilled react-router-dom, and also import BrowserRouter as Router,
Switch,
Route,
Link

What is the problem? I can not figure it out.

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './component/Navbar/Navbar';
import Product from './component/Product/Product';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route,Link} from "react-router-dom";
import UpComing from './component/UpComing/UpComing';
import NotFound from './component/NotFound/NotFound';
import OrderReview from './component/OrderReview/OrderReview';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route to="/product">
            <Product></Product>
          </Route>
          <Route to="/OrderReview">
            <OrderReview></OrderReview>
          </Route>
          <Route exact to="/">
            <Product></Product>
          </Route>
          <Route to="*">
            <NotFound></NotFound>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working" ?You have a few things to change here: first, your components should not be rendered using <MyComponent></MyComponent> if they do not have any children. You can replace them with <MyComponent />.

Comment: You should use `path` property of `Route`, not the `to`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `path` instead of `to` on your routes. `to` is used for `Link` components. I've created a minimal representation of your code working on codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-router-playground-g0uzc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark